# How can I make the Outlook "To" field allow auto completion for all my contacts?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

When we make a new mail message in Outlook 2007 and try to write any letter in `To` field it shows an auto complete list with all available contacts that contain written letters.

This list is displaying all emails that you have send to them before and over time this list grows as you send to more and more new contacts...

**My Issues:** When we reinstall Windows, install new copy of Outlook, create a new mail message, try to write any character in `To` field it will not show any contacts and this leads to write it or choose from contacts. Is it in any way possible to make Outlook's contacts, or specific contacts I determine to be cached, appear in `TO` when I write any letter without need to write them again?

Comment: As an aside: pressing (if I remember correctly) Ctrl-K invokes some "check names" function, which will validate the names given your own address book. Though it's not auto-complete, it does allow for just typing part of the name and then press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may be too late for now, this may prove useful in future. The cache is stored in a file with a .nk2 extension, which can be [transferred from one PC to another](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA011394511033.ASPX).

I'm not aware of any utility for creating or modifying an .nk2 file.

Comment: Thanks for these valuable info , i do search and i found this http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html can edit .nk2 files

Comment: also i found this http://www.nk2.info/

Comment: Cool, looks like NirSoft's utility may be just the thing for you.

Comment: NirSoft's utilities for all sorts of things are great, and simply get the job done well. He only just released this latest version of the nk2 editor, which does enable you to create entries from nothing, so it may well be possible to export your contacts' email addresses then parse them in something like Exel to the right format for importing